# Magento Info Block in Payment Method

Tags: magento

does anyone know how do I include a block information when selecting a payment method in my checkout page? within that block I want to insert an html(image) from the payment gateway that I'm using.

I've tried to do this using jquery inserting the html needed when the page loads, the image appears quickly but some update in the layout of the checkout page removes the image, ie, it appears and disappears soon after.

I am very new to magento and any help would be welcome, thanks

I´m using magento 1.8.1

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are referring to the right blocks which output the checkout progress ( see below if you are referring to the actual payment method selection step ).

You don't need to do any client side scripting. Magento supports that by default.

### Checkout progress ( right blocks on checkout page ):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Open your Payment Method model.
2. Add the following code:

   protected $_infoBlockType = 'mymodule/info';

The block code should look like:

```
<?php

    class Company_MyModule_Block_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cc
    {
        protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
        {
            $info = $this->getInfo();
            $transport = new Varien_Object(array('My Var' => "My Value"));
            return $transport;
        }
    }
```

### Payment method selection step:

If you are referring to the actual payment method selection step, when you click on a payment method and a small form appears under it you need to:

1. Add the following code in your payment model:

   protected $_formBlockType = "mymodule/form";

You also need to create the mymodule/form:

```
<?php

    class Company_MyModule_Block_Form extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Cc
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setTemplate('path/to/template.phtml');
        }
  }
```

The template file should look something like:

```
<?php $_code=$this->getMethodCode(); ?>

<fieldset class="form-list">
    <ul style="display: none;" id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code ?>">
        <li>
            <p>here is my custom content!:)</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```